# Windows phone location tracking program

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to make a windows phone app that gets the users location and then checks wether their location is within a certain area (a mapped out polygon or inside a square of coordinates) and then deliver information based on if they are within that area or not.  This is referred to as geofencing.  Is their an API out their on an example of this that makes this very easy?  All I want to do is map out a location and see if the users coordinates are within that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use MovementThreshold property in GeoCoordinateWatcher. here please mention the distance in meter. So if the corresponding distance crossed you will get notification in Position_Changed Callback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IF you're going to show the current location in a map, then you could simply go for the guidance provided by msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735578(v=vs.105).aspx).

Or else if you just wanted to use the `Geo Coordinates, have a look at [this](http://abundantcode.com/how-to-get-the-current-location-in-windows-phone-8/).

For you to continue with the `GeoFencing`, this would be helpful [Setting up a geofence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn322032.aspx)

Hope it helps!